# How to avoid initializing entrypoint of inherited module

Tags: gwt

I have an GWT module, which defines an entry point that builds an UI (let's call this module A).

I inherit module A in another module (say module B), which builds its own UI via its own entry point, reusing classes defined in inherited module A.

My problem is, when I initialize module B, entry points from both Module A and B are instantiated and triggered (via onModuleLoad method). This results in both entry points modifying same UI in turn, resulting in corrupt page.

So, I want to inherit a module, but I don't want its entry points activated during application initialization. How can I inherit a module, but avoid initialization of its entry point class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of inheriting A from B, and adding more entrypoints that need to be built, consider making a third module. The new one, Z should be the common code that both A and B need, and should not have an entrypoint. This way, both A and B can inherit from Z and each add their own entrypoint as needed.

---

If the above can't be used (for example if you can't edit A), another option could be to add a new module in the same package as A, call it A2, and give it the same contents of A, minus the EntryPoint. Then, B can inherit from A2 instead.

Comment: Should have thought of this :)  Thanks.